# Use JQuery for change a image in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems to change an image using JQuery.

The fragment from my `hmtl.erb`:

```
<%= image_tag('empty-screen.png', style:'width: 100%', class:'img-responsive center-block', id:'screen-d') %>
```

Fragment from my `javascript`:

```
$("#collapseOne").on('show.bs.collapse',function () {
        $('#screen-d').attr("src","#{asset_path('empty-screen.png')}");
    });
```

The real problem is that I don't know very well how Rails uses the asset pipeline. I believed that using `asset_path` would work, but with that code I was just changing the `src` to `#{asset_path('empty-screen.png')}`. So I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#collapseOne").on('show.bs.collapse',function () {
    $('#screen-d').attr("src","<%= asset_path('empty-screen.png') %>");
});
```

And make sure to add a .erb at the end of your .js file

Comment: Thanks but didn't work, I changed it for `$('#screen-d').attr("src","<%= asset_path('complex-screen.png') %>");` and worked, it's that fine?

Comment: Whats the difference except the image name ?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot Your answer still shows the `#{ ... }`, that's why it didn't work.  OP removed them and it worked.